# searching same string in all the open file in vi editor

Tags: editor, vi

I am new to vi editor , I learnt that we can open multiple files using (new : filename), is there any way to search a string in all the open files with a single search , that is without toggling window and searching .

with regards
deepak

Comment: why push yourself for something so trivial, use grep to find anything on a number of files.

Answer (score 1):

try

:bufdo g/searchstring/

multiple packages providing this functionality exist, e.g. [compview](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1803) , [greputils](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1062).